# Can anyone identify this surface-mount sensor?

Tags: mosfet, led, diodes, integrated-circuit, hall-effect

The picture shows a part of a brushless motor. The sensor looks like it may be a Hall-effect sensor, but I'm not sure. Can anyone help me identify it?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Please edit the question and add a 2nd photo to provide context for the first: zoom out a bit so that we an see what device this sensor is in. I'm guessing it's a BLD motor, but that's just a guess. We really need a 2nd photo that captures the whole "thing" to understand what's going on.

Comment: Almost certainly a hall effect sensor indeed. Certainly not surface mount.